# LWC Data table not showing Default Value on load & value user selected by choosing picklist

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I've created a LWC Data Table with Custom Data type(Combo box with Picklist).I've tried to display default values in that combo box on uploading an excel file.Everything is working fine.How ever the default values of combobox are not shown up on UI.Where as they are actually mapped behind and records are created when I click on save button.The same component is working fine in Other Sandbox and default values are being shown.

```
<lightning-input type="file" label=" Upload " onchange={excelFileToJson} disabled={disableButton} accept="xlsx" multiple="false"></lightning-input>

<c-case-datatable
  key-field="Id"
   data={finalData}
   columns={columns}
   record-id={recordId}
   hide-checkbox-column="true"
   onsave={handleSave}
   oncancel={handleCancel}
   onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged} 
   draft-values={draftValues}>
</c-case-datatable>
```

````
@track columns = [
  { label: 'Field API Values',fieldName: 'FieldAPI__c',type: 'text',},
  { label: 'Excel Values',type:'casePicklist',wrapText:true,editable: true,
typeAttributes: {
  placeholder: 'Please Choose',
  options: { fieldName : 'picklistOptions' },
  context: { fieldName: 'FieldAPI__c' },
  value:{ fieldName: 'selectedValue' },
  
} 
}
];
excelFileToJson(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let files = event.target.files;
            if(files){
            this.fileUploaded = false;
            }
            const analysisExcel = (file) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
                reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
            });
            analysisExcel(files[0])
            .then((result) => {
                let datas = []; //  Store the acquired data 
                let XLSX = window.XLSX;
                let workbook = XLSX.read(result, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });
                for (let sheet in workbook.Sheets) {
                    if (workbook.Sheets.hasOwnProperty(sheet)) {
                       datas = datas.concat(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet]));
                    }
                }
                this.dataList = datas;
                this.fetchCaseMetaData();
  
                const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                    variant: "success",
                    message: ' The file has been uploaded and parsed successfully ',
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            });
        }

fetchCaseMetaData() {
    let options = [];
    for (let i in this.dataList) {
      var key = i;
      var val = this.dataList[i];
      for (var j in val) {
        let option = options.find(o => o.label === j);
        if (option) {
          option.value.push(val[j]);
        } else {
          options.push({ label: j, value: [val[j]] });
        }
      }
    }
    let cdata = [];
    this.caseTemplateMetadata.forEach((record, index) => {
      let fieldAPIValues = record.FieldAPI__c.split(',');
      fieldAPIValues.forEach((fieldAPIValue, index) => {
        cdata.push({
          Label: record.Label,
          FieldAPI__c: fieldAPIValue,
          picklistOptions: options,
          selectedValue: options[index].value
        });
      });
    });
    this.draftValues =  [{}];
    this.finalData = cdata.slice();
    this.error = undefined;
}```

```caseDatatable.HTML
<template>   
</template>```
```caseDatatable.JavaScript
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import casePicklist from './casePicklist\.html'

export default class CaseDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes ={
        casePicklist:{
            template:casePicklist,
            standardCellLayout:true,
            typeAttributes:['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context']
        }
    }
}```
```casePicklist.HTML
<template>
    <c-datatable-picklist label={typeAttributes.label}  value={typeAttributes.value} 
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}  options={typeAttributes.options} context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-datatable-picklist>
</template>```
```datatablePicklist.html
<template>
    <div class="picklist-container">
    <lightning-combobox 
        name="picklist" 
        label={label}
        value={value} 
        placeholder={placeholder} 
        options={options} 
        onchange={handleChange}
        variant='label-hidden'
        data-inputable="true">
    </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>```
```datatablePicklist.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatablePicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api options;
    @api value;
    @api context;
    

    handleChange(event) {
        //show the selected value on UI
        this.value = event.detail.value;

        //fire event to send context and selected value to the data table
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('picklistchanged', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                data: {context: this.context, value: this.value}
            }
        }));
    }

}```
````

Comment: Can you also share the code of datatable?

Comment: Hi @MukulMahawariya added the complete code